# Two listen threads for the same message

Tags: c#, client

I have a question. I'm building a game with a server and client based on tcp in Windows Forms using C#. I run some threads that listen on port 8820 and each thread is on different form.

My question is: are both listening threads going to get messages from the server, or is the first that gets it the only one to get it?

Comment: logically they both should receive the message.

Comment: As stated, without a good [mcve], this question is far too broad, as we have no idea what the code looks like. The question is also unclear: if you are _listening_ on a port then _your_ socket is the server, so it makes no sense to ask if your threads which are _listening_ will get messages from some _other_ server. Without using the "reuse" flag, you're not going to have more than one socket listening on a given port anyway. I will tell you: you should have only a single UI thread, so by "different form" you are referring to a [tag:winforms] `Form` object you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you'll have two `TcpListener`s running, each on a different form, but for the same port, like this:

```
// Runs on Form #1
TcpListener tcp1 = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 9876);
tcp1.Start();

// Runs on Form #2
TcpListener tcp2 = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 9876);
tcp2.Start();
```

The second one to start will throw a SocketException.  You can only have one listener for a given port/network address.